Model shows up as dots and lines
I first downloaded these files from the Steam Website here:
https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=3066409360
Next, I went ahead and downloaded the 4.1 version of Blender. I've watched multiple You tube videos on how to import MDL files. One of them told me to install Blender source tools into Blender and download Crowbar to decompile the MDL files so I went and did that after I downloaded the files from the Steam Workshop download site. After I downloaded the files I decompiled them, tried to import them into Blender numerous times and it kept giving me
ERROR No such directory found; No armature Found
Then, I went and watched another video saying that I needed The Source IO add-on and went and installed that. I gave it a try and tells me the same thing. So, then I tried decompiling one the files (to test if it would work) into an SMD file. I gave that a shot and it kind of worked. Instead of having a complete model it shows up as dots and lines like this:
I've tried everything that I could possibly think doing at this point.
As far as importing mdl files go. Now I'm new to this whole blender thing and I may be missing something or doing something wrong. Either that or the files are damaged or corrupt and I just dont know it. But, after almost 2 weeks trying to figure out how to resolve this issue with these files, I've ran out ideas on how to fix this. I don't know what else to do. Can anyone Please help me with this?
